# Read in Fortran a matrix saved with tobytes in Python

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, binaryfiles

I saved a matrix in Python with `ndarray.tobytes(order='F')`.

```
f_mat = open('mat.dat', 'wb')
f_mat.write(matrix.tobytes('F'))
f_mat.close()
```

Is there a quick way to read it in Fortran or should I do a for cycle and figure out the order of the elements?

Comment: Sorry but in Fortran (at least older ones) you really need to know how big is the record in bytes and in what sequence you're writing data if you're using binary.

Comment: Not necessarily a record, but you should know what you are actually reading. What do the bytes mean. If you know the size and type, it should be just one read statement.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am looking for. I know my matrix to be a 3600 x 7200 matrix with floats in python. However I don't know how to tell Fortran to read a matrix from binaries...I always used the read statement for one variable per time, like 
     read(10,END=999,ERR=1000)  realvalue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the size (`n` time `m`) and the type of the array and declare it accordingly:

```
!just an example
real(c_double), allocatable :: mat(:,:)
allocate(mat(n,m))
```

it should be just

```
open(newunit = u, file='mat.dat', access='stream', form='unformatted', status='old', action='read')
read(u) mat
close(u)
```

The arguments to `open` after `access='stream'` are optional.